# CORS strict-origin-when-cross-origin issues

Tags: cors

Our company website (sector5digital.com - running on Wordpress) has a video that plays in the background of the homepage. This has been working for several years. The video is hosted on Digital Ocean under sitecdn.sector5digital.com. The home page references the video at https://sitecdn.sector5digital.com/S5DShowreel2023.mp4

Recently I was asked to swap the video out for a newer updated video. I uploaded the new video to the same digital ocean bucket and updated the Wordpress settings to point to the new video. Some of our employees though are now getting a strict-origin-when-cross-origin when trying to pull the video from the cdn - while it works fine for me.

On Digital Ocean, I have CORS configured for http:// * .sector5digital.com for GET and HEAD requests, with 1 allowed header of * . The same configuration also exists for https:// * .sector5digital.com, http://sector5digital.com and https://sector5digital.com

I am quite stumped by why this is occuring, and am hoping someone can get me pointed in the right direction for a fix.

I have asked users to clear browser cache, thinking maybe it was a cache issue, but to no avail.

Edit: The CORS settings do not have a space between https:// and the * - stackoverflow doesn't show the * though if there isn't a space...

[Chrome Dev Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JltGv.png)

Comment: Yes sounds like a caching issue but also remember that a CDN is a caching system, pro tip though CONTROL-F5 forces a re-download

Comment: The new video .. is it a new name or the old name?  If you used the same name, it might not download the new version.  A trick though you can use is appehend to the url with a ?v101 or something and even though the file name is the same, it often triggers a new cache call and downloads the new things even with the old file name.  Granted this is an IIS thing but I suspect its similar.

Comment: @easleyfixed Pressing CTRL-F5 did not make a difference.

The name is a new filename. The old video still exists as WebsiteHeader.mp4 (https://sitecdn.sector5digital.com/WebsiteHeader.mp4)

Comment: Do you have control over the CDN panel?  Maybe there are some cache controls in there you could force it to clear out and rebuild so it automatically downloads each time, its sounding like when they hit the site, its not downloading the new content, and just using the local version.  Have you tried to connect to it from a computer that has NEVER been there and see if it does the old or new video?

Comment: CDN allows me to set a cache duration (it's currently set to 1 hour).
It also allows me to purge the cache, which I tried to no effect. Its going to be a couple hours before I can get to a "clean" computer to test on.

Comment: well that covers all those bases.  I know when I had some things like this with a PLESK host using CloudFlair CDN years ago it took like 2 full days before EVERY system always showed up properly so was very hard to pin down until it was certain.  But yeah the clean system is the true test, if it goes to the new one you are good and its just the clients that are derped, but if the fresh system shows the old video .. thats going to be curious.

Comment: Realized I didn't have to wait a couple of hours, there are a couple of windows servers I have access to in our AWS environment. Same CORS issue.
Note that the users are not getting the old video (just the new video does not load because of CORS).
Also edited my original post to include a image of the chome dev console in case I'm just missing something obvious there.
And I did try and add a ?v1 to the end of the filename on the off chance there might be something with that.

Comment: Can you share any CORS errors that occur in the dev console? The request for https://sitecdn.sector5digital.com/S5DShowreel2023.mp4?v1 fails because of an invalid server certificate (expired on Thursday, June 10, 2021 at 1:59:59 AM).

Comment: @HeikoTheißen this is the key to what I was missing. Apparently at some point in the past I'd disabled Chrome's security check for this site, so I wasn't having issues pulling it while co-workers were not able to. Please post the (very) outdated SSL cert as the answer to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server certificate of https://sitecdn.sector5digital.com was expired, that's why the request failed because of invalid certificate.

The server certificate has meanwhile been updated and is now valid.